# GCC adds weird temporal variables

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I have created this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;
uint in[2]={1,2},out[2]={3,4};

int main() {

    in[0]=out[0]/10;
}
```

and compiled it with GCC (v4.4.5,no optimizations) on Linux, the resulting assembly is:

```
0000000000400474 <main>:
400474:       55                      push   rbp
400475:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
400478:       8b 05 ae 03 20 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x2003ae]        # 0082c <out>
40047e:       89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
400481:       ba cd cc cc cc          mov    edx,0xcccccccd
400486:       8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
400489:       f7 e2                   mul    edx
40048b:       89 d0                   mov    eax,edx
40048d:       c1 e8 03                shr    eax,0x3
400490:       89 05 8e 03 20 00       mov    DWORD PTR [rip+0x20038e],eax        # 600824 <in>
400496:       c9                      leave
400497:       c3                      ret
400498:       90                      nop
400499:       90                      nop
40049a:       90                      nop
40049b:       90                      nop
40049c:       90                      nop
40049d:       90                      nop
40049e:       90                      nop
40049f:       90                      nop
```

Now, the question is: what is this code doing on line #5 ?

```
40047e:       89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
```

isn't it storing the value it got from out[0] again in some place in memory? Why so? I didn't tell it to read and write immediatly to some location.

Now, this temporal variable appears again at the address 400486 on line #7:

```
400486:       8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
```

It looks like in this example GCC is producing very inefficient code, and it will evict the cache line because of these temporal storages. Please confirm, maybe there is something I am not getting.

Comment: Well, you did say no optimization.

Comment: Of course it's producing inefficient code; you told it not to optimize.

Comment: Isn't `rbp-0x4` the stack? It previously does `mov rbp, rsp`.

Comment: It just saves onto and restore the value of `%eax` from the stack.. Your arrays are at `%ebx + 0x20038e`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC makes very inefficient code when compiling on `-O0` - what you're seeing is basically a raw translation of its internal representation of the program. This internal representation includes a number of temporary variables, and your load/store pair here is a value passing through such a temporary. On higher optimization levels these kinds of useless loads/stores will mostly be eliminated; however on `-O0` even the simplest of analysis is disabled.

Comment: I guess its IL must be a stack-based machine; I added `return argc;` and it copied argc to the stack before returning it. (I also tried changing in and out to simple variables, and it copied `(1 << 32) * 0.8` to the stack.) By comparison even at `/Od` the MSVC compiler generally emits `mov eax, _out` `xor edx, edx` `mov ecx, 10` `div ecx` `mov _in, eax`. (It uses mul at `/O2`.)

Comment: @Neil: GCC has several different Intermediate Representations: GIMPLE, SSA, RTL, ... Of course the SSA form creates loads of temporary variables.

Comment: thanks I got it. I was thinking that the original code generated by GCC will do what it is told to do even with -O0, not saving and restoring register values.

Comment: nitpick on an old comment: SSA isn't separate from GIMPLE.  GIMPLE is GCC's [SSA (Static single-assignment)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form) representation of the program logic.  Like LLVM's IR.  It's like calling a bowl of oranges (SSA) and apples (RTL) a bowl of oranges, citrus, and apples.